# Django is not fetching data from the database even if the row being queried already exists

Tags: django-forms, django-queryset, django-database

This is the view for my login

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    global email_address1, password1, ea, psd, i
    form = Login()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_address1 = request.POST.get('Email Address')
        password1 = request.POST.get('Password')
        try:
            i = UserInfo.objects.get(email_address=email_address1)
        except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
            i = None
        if i!= None:
            ea = str(i.email_address)
            psd = str(i.password)
            if email_address1 == ea and password1 == psd:
                return redirect("home")

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {"form": form})
```

and this is the model I'm calling

models.py:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

when I check in the /admin page the email address already exists, but it still isn't fetching it

my best guess is that there's some problem while registering the user

views.py:

```
def new_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = NewForm()
    return render(request, "users/newregister.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
def login(request):
    global email_address1, password1, ea, psd, i
    form = Login()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_address1 = request.POST.get('Email Address')
        password1 = request.POST.get('Password')
        try:
            i = UserInfo.objects.get(email_address=email_address1).
            ea = str(i.email_address)
            psd = str(i.password)
            if email_address1 == ea and password1 == psd:
                return redirect("home")
        except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
            i = None
            print(i)

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem of retrieving from the database unfortunately. I tried changing it to this.